# Implementing a "Find Friends by phone number" feature on App Engine using datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

One of the core functions of my messaging app is allowing users to find friends who are also on the service based on their phone numbers. Apps like Whatsapp and Snapchat do have the same kind of mechanism.

I'm struggling to find a solution that returns a good number of results. I'm wondering how most other apps approach this pretty widely implemented feature.

My current implementation is that I have User model and a PhoneUser model. The PhoneUser model is keyed on the user's phone number that has been converted into the standardized E164 format. It has a KeyProperty to link it to the respective user.

```
class PhoneUser(ndb.Model):
    # id is the phone number in E164 format
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User', required=True)
```

When a user signs up for the service and grants access to their phone contacts, the app can get a large number of phone numbers from the user's phone book. 1,000 numbers is not impossible. I convert all these numbers into the standardized E164 format and then build keys for each (ie. ndb.Key('PhoneUser', PHONE_NUMBER)). With that list of PhoneUser keys, I can use ndb.get_multi(list_of_phoneuser_keys). This lets me avoid querying for 1,000 numbers.

This theoretically works well under the assumption that users enter their phone numbers with country code correctly so that the python phonenumbers library can parse it.

However, that is many times not the case, but this approach requires it because getting entities by keys requires exact matches.

This was just one approach I had thought of and it has its drawbacks. This seems like a very common function in apps and I was wondering if there was a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

In any case you'll need to normalize phone numbers to common format (E164). We use [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/), which works pretty well. You might check out the [python port](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers).

We replace missing country codes in friends phone numbers with the country code of the user doing the search. Rationale: if user does not have a country code entered for his contact, then they are probably from the same country.

Hint: things will get interesting when you will want to implement reverse-search - notifying existing users that one of their friends showed up in the network.

Comment: I'm at a similar place, how did you import the python port? (I usually import and fix issues manually, hope there is an easier way for libphonenumber)

Answer (score -1):

The right way would be not to rely on users placing city/county codes and/or prefixes. I dont know anyone that saves their numbers with country codes unless they travel frequently oversees.
You will need to parse and correct the numbers. You can use current geolocation to try and add missing city/country codes and also remove unneeded prefixes. Probably involves some research into your target country audiences.

Comment: not clear why this was marked -1 without any explanation. Remains the correct answer.